# Wordpress: Saving the Page URL as a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I have a function in Wordpress that I BELIEVE should be getting the URL of the page a visitor is sitting on. It's as follows:

```
function get_request_url() {
$formurl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Then, for fun, I have a PHP enabled widget with:

```
<?php echo get_request_url() ; ?>
```

However, it always shows no value.  I don't get errors, just... nothing.

I'm a pretty novice coder, and I hacked this together from a few different sources (I know, I know... search engine code snippet alchemy can be bad for your health), so I think I've either skipped a step, or missed the point entirely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Your function needs to add a return

```
function get_request_url() { 
    $formurl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $formurl;
}
```

Comment: Oh jeez.  Thank you.  Should have known that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function get_request_url() {
    $formurl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $formurl;
}
```